# Get grouped data from a table as columns instead of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following schema: (Date, Name, Status) where State can be one of 'Processing', 'Active' and 'Closed'. Sample entries are:

```
|------------+---------+------------|
|       Date | Name    | Status     |
|------------+---------+------------|
| 2011-07-01 | Alice   | Processing |
| 2011-07-01 | Alice   | Active     |
| 2011-07-02 | Alice   | Closed     |
| 2011-07-01 | Bob     | Active     |
| 2011-07-02 | Charlie | Processing |
|------------+---------+------------|
```

I am using the following query to get a count of number of accounts in different statuses:

```
select date, status, count(distinct name)
from accounts
group by date, status
```

And it gives the following:

```
2011-07-01 Processing 1
2011-07-01 Active 2
2011-07-02 Active 1
2011-07-02 Closed 1
```

How can I get the data in columns? i.e.,

```
2011-07-01 2 1 0
2011-07-02 1 0 1
```

Where the first column is date, second column is number of accounts in Active status, third column is number of accounts in Processing status and the last column is number of accounts in Closed status? The only I can think of is writing three sub-queries for each of the statuses and doing a parent query to select each of them. But it doesn't seem very extensible (e.g., if I have to add a new status, I have modify the parent query and add one more sub-query).

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Oracle at the moment (not sure which version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT date
   , SUM(CASE status WHEN 'Active'     THEN cnt ELSE 0 END) AS a
   , SUM(CASE status WHEN 'Processing' THEN cnt ELSE 0 END) AS p
   , SUM(CASE status WHEN 'Closed'     THEN cnt ELSE 0 END) AS c
FROM 
  ( SELECT date, status, COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS cnt
    FROM accounts
    GROUP BY date, status
  ) grp
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: This one contains a syntax error and "date" can never be a real column, but in case a name can have the same status on a certain day more than once, this query is the one.

Comment: @Rob: OK, I got that, it's the `AS` in the table alias. Oracle doesn't like that.

Answer (score 2):

The exact syntax will depend on your database engine, but in PostgreSQL, and probably others, this will work. This may work verbatim in Oracle, as Postgres tends to copy Oracle syntax a lot.

```
SELECT
    date,
    SUM((Status='Processing')::INT) AS Processing,
    SUM((Status='Active')::INT) AS Active,
    SUM((Status='Closed')::INT) AS Closed
FROM accounts
GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: Is the cast with `::INT` Oracle syntax as well?

Answer (score 2):

you can use build in pivot function in oracle as well...

```
SELECT * FROM accounts 
pivot ( count(distinct name) for status in ('Active','Processing','Closed'));
```

this function is suggested by person having good experience in oracle database.. that's why i pasted here :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard way (before Oracle 11g) to do a pivot:

```
SQL> create table mytable (mydate,name,status)
  2  as
  3  select date '2011-07-01', 'Alice', 'Processing' from dual union all
  4  select date '2011-07-01', 'Alice', 'Active' from dual union all
  5  select date '2011-07-02', 'Alice', 'Closed' from dual union all
  6  select date '2011-07-01', 'Bob', 'Active' from dual union all
  7  select date '2011-07-02', 'Charlie', 'Processing' from dual
  8  /

Table created.

SQL> select mydate
  2       , count(case status when 'Active' then 1 end)     a
  3       , count(case status when 'Processing' then 1 end) p
  4       , count(case status when 'Closed' then 1 end)     c
  5    from mytable
  6   group by mydate
  7   order by mydate
  8  /

MYDATE                       A          P          C
------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
01-07-2011 00:00:00          2          1          0
02-07-2011 00:00:00          0          1          1

2 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: This would not count `DISTINCT` names states, would it?

Comment: True. If that is the requirement, the original poster needs your query.